# Restore xubuntu dock

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I 've installed xubuntu desktop on ubuntu 14.04 from the reppositores with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` ,and i see that the dock doesn't appear ,how can i restore it?

Comment: Did you try `xfdesktop -R` and `xfce4-panel -r` ?